# Getting a string from the user: Problem with Getting unwanted words into the array

Tags: c

when I try to write this code:

```
int main(){
    /*1.*/char A[16];
    /*2.*/char B[16];
    /*3.*/char C[16];
    /*4.*/scanf(" %15[^\n]",A);
    /*5.*/scanf(" %15[^\n]",B);
    /*6.*/scanf(" %15[^\n]",C);
```

and for example after line 4 the input I getting from the user is: "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"(30*a).
So the array A gets the input : "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" (15 times), and when I reach line 5 ,it jumps to line 6 and the array B gets the input: "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" (15 times).
How can this be prevented? And allow the user to insert his input into array B ?

Comment: Stop using `scanf`.

Comment: Obligatory http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can eat up the characters until `\n`.

To do that you can use `%*[\n]` specification.

Where `%*[\n]`specification reads and ignores the characters until it reaches `\n`.

**Example:**

```
scanf(" %15s%*[^\n]",A);
scanf(" %15s%*[^\n]",B);
scanf(" %15s%*[^\n]",C);
```

Comment: But why you didn't delete the %s ?? the %[] is a format on its own

Comment: With only %[] remaining characters will be left out in the stream so you need %s followed by %*[^\n] to read the string and clear the remaining characters.

Comment: But now I see that there is a problem with your answer, the answer is a private case of the problem I mentioned.
What happens if I want to do the same operation for the three strings in the same line ???

Comment: what did you ask and what are you expecting now. Clearly you cannot do both. Either enter the input in separate line or same line not both.

Comment: I mentioned a specific case of a problem, but I expected an answer that would solve the problem in various variations.
I mean if, for example, I cut the 3 rows into one row and write:

Comment: scanf(" %15s%*[^\n] %15s%*[^\n] %15s%*[^\n]",A,B,C)
it will not work.

Comment: No that you cannot . For same line  you could use %15s%15s%15s  but it will not work for multiple lines.

Comment: Take time and think what are you asking.

Comment: More correctly for one line to use:
%15[^\n] %15[^\n] %15[^\n]

Comment: Yes if you want to include space.

Comment: Better, as @melpomene says, "stop using `scanf()`".